# ORA-00936: missing expression in Data Reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

im trying to create log in page in my asp.net webform
im new in asp.net 
this code is what i do in c# windows form 
is it same in asp.net because it returns me a error "ORA-00936: missing expression"

```
string query = "Select EMPID,PASSWRD from TBLUSERS where EMPID = @UserID and PASSWRD = @password";
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query,con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID",OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OracleDbType.Varchar2);

                cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = txtxUserName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = txtPaswword.Text;

                OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {

                }
else{}
```

this code should work in winform i think but its not working when i use this in asp.net

Comment: Check your parameters at least one of them should be null. This is why

Comment: why it should be null?

Comment: `where EMPID = @UserID and PASSWRD = @password";` --> `where EMPID = '@UserID' and PASSWRD = '@password' ";` I.E. add single quotes as it seems like column's data type is Varchar2

Comment: ahh so in oracle Varchar2 data type the parameter should have ' ' not like in mysql

Comment: You got it @VonJustineNapalang